# pondjs not recognised after installing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm using Webstorm IDE and have created a create-react-app. I installed [pondjs](https://github.com/esnet/pond) using:

```
npm install pondjs --save
```

it got installed and that's why I can see it in node-modules.

But in my App.js when I'm trying to import it using :

```
import { TimeSeries, TimeRange } from "pondjs";
```

this package is not recognised. Please help. I'm trying to solve this since long.

Answer (score 1):

Use `require` instead of `import`.

`const { TimeSeries, TimeRange } = require('pondjs');`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but installing the alpha version of pond.js fixed the issue in my case.

```sh
yarn install pondjs@1.0.0-alpha.0
```

Importing pond.js in the project:

```js
import { timeSeries } from "pondjs";
```